# Nodejs and Meteor on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, meteor, deployment, openshift, ionic2

I have a mobile (*Ionic 2*) chat application with the [following implementation](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup), that uses `nodejs-0.10` and `MongoDB 3.2.7` and `Meteor 1.4.1.1`. It works perfectly on my `localhost`.

Now I need to **deploy it to an *OpenShift* server**. I have followed the [following steps](https://github.com/jeeeyul/meteor-openshift) and created a server on OpenShift with `Meteor`. It is connecting with *Git*, and I can push my code to the server.

I am pretty sure the `Meteor` server is running on *OpenShift*, because I saw something to that effect on the startup logs (via ssh). However, I am not sure how to connect to the `Meteor` server to test it.

[image]

The domain is `nodejs-easyjobs.rhcloud.com` (`54.208.77.250`) on the *OpenShift* server, I can ping this successfully.

I am using Ionic 2 to build the mobile app. I am currently just running on `Android`, but plan to add `iOS` and `Windows`.

I am following [this](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup) tutorial, and it runs on `localhost`. However, I am not sure where this is configured. I guess localhost is default, and you need to change it to a different host if needs be.

If I check my *OpenShift* server (`nodejs-easyjobs.rhcloud.com`) via ssh, I can see that the contents of the *Meteor* bundle directory is on the server. So *Git* is pushing the code.

The part I don't understand is:

- Do I need to configure *Meteor* differently for being on the *OpenShift*
  Server? Or do I just leave it as is?
- Where do I configure the client
  (*Ionic 2*) to point to the *OpenShift* server?

**Question:**

My question is, how do I configure my mobile app (*Ionic 2*) to connect to the *OpenShift* Meteor Server?

UPDATE:

My dir structure:

```
openshift-appname
    .../ionic-apps/nodejs/bundle/server/...
meteorapp
    .../ionic-aps/myIonicApp/api/.meteor/...
    .../ionic-aps/myIonicApp/api/server/...
```

The contents of the `.../ionic-apps/nodejs` is cloned on the *OpenShift* server with *Git*.

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/jeeeyul/meteor-openshift) to deploy the Meteor bundle to OpenShift. `

So I used the following to **build** my *Meteor* app:

```
> cd .../ionic-aps/myIonicApp/
> meteor build .../ionic-apps/nodejs --directory --server-only
```

As far as I can see, I may be wrong, but the Meteor Server is all correct and running on OpenShift. I need to know how I can get my Ionic2 app to access it.

- Step1: Find the access point to the *Meteor* server using the *OpenShift*
  IP. i.e. `nodejs-easyjobs.rhcloud.com (54.208.77.250)`.
- Step2: Configure my *Ionic2* client to use this.

Comment: This may provide some answers:  https://forums.meteor.com/t/develop-and-deploy-server-side-independently-from-client-side-ionic-meteor/21810/10